# Is there a way to save the data on SharedPreference?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, cs50

I am trying to save data on button toggle, so that if pokemon is caught, when i run the application again, pokemon is caugt, and when released, It toggles back to "catch". But all my pokemon are displaying caught (button shows "release")

```
package com.example.pokedex;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class PokemonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView nameTextView;
    private TextView numberTextView;
    private TextView type1TextView;
    private TextView type2TextView;
    private String url;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    Button button;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    public static final String mypreference = "mypref";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokemon);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        nameTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokedex_name);
        numberTextView = findViewById(R.id.pokedex_number);
        type1TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokedex_type);
        type2TextView = findViewById(R.id.pokedex_type2);
        button = findViewById(R.id.catcher);

        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        load();

    }

    public void load() {
        type1TextView.setText("");
        type2TextView.setText("");

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, response -> {
            try {
                nameTextView.setText(response.getString("name"));
                numberTextView.setText(String.format("#%03d", response.getInt("id")));

                JSONArray typeEntries = response.getJSONArray("types");
                for (int i = 0; i < typeEntries.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject typeEntry = typeEntries.getJSONObject(i);
                    int slot = typeEntry.getInt("slot");
                    String type = typeEntry.getJSONObject("type").getString("name");

                    if (slot == 1) {
                        type1TextView.setText(type);
                    } else if (slot == 2) {
                        type2TextView.setText(type);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("cs50", "Pokemon json error", e);
            }
        }, error -> Log.e("cs50", "Pokemon details error", error));

        requestQueue.add(request);

        if (sharedpreferences.contains(nameTextView.getText().toString()))
            button.setText("Release");
    }


    public void toggleCatch(View view) {
        String name = nameTextView.getText().toString();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

        if (button.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("Catch".toLowerCase())) {
            //editor.clear();
            editor.putString(name, name);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
            button.setText("Release");

        } else if (button.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals("Release".toLowerCase())){
            editor.remove(name);
            editor.apply();
            editor.commit();
            button.setText("Catch");
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything i know how to, please help.

Unmodified source code at "https://cdn.cs50.net/2019/fall/tracks/android/pokedex/pokedex.zip"

Comment: Can you describe the flow of testing you are executing? Does all Pokemons appear caught upon installing and first run of your app or rather you install and start your app, catch one pokemon and after that all pokemons shows up as caught? Also, since you are using Pokemon names as keys, are all Pokemons in your app have distinct names?

Comment: On first install, non should be caught, button should display (CATCH), but when caught button changes to (RELEASE). However whenever i start the app, all buttons are displaying (RELEASE). And yes, pokemon names are the keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line of code

```
if (sharedpreferences.contains(nameTextView.getText().toString()))
            button.setText("Release");
```

should go into your **onResponseListener()** that is your `response -> ....`

Currently you are calling the if statement above synchronously. This means that you are searching for not any valid Pokemon name but "" (empty string) inside **SharedPreferences**. In one of your tests, you probably saved empty string as a key, and you cannot undo that because any transaction after you load your pokemons includes a non-empty string Pokemon name.

If taht is indeed the case, you can easily add a temporary code inside your activity **onCreate()** method to remove that entry from **SharedPreferences**.

Comment: You have saved me. I literally can not thank you enough for this answer. I had given up and submitted the work with it partially working. THANK YOU SO MUCH